# Applescript, Photoshop, Opening Files

Tags: photoshop, automation

I am trying to use Applescript to automate a task in photoshop.

When attempting to open a file:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"

    -- Open the first image
    set filePath to alias "Users:jameshale:Pictures:DSC_1273.jpg"
    with timeout of 5 seconds
        open filePath as Camera RAW
    end timeout

end tell
```

The result is an error:

```
error "Adobe Photoshop CS5 got an error: Can’t get alias \"Users:jameshale:Pictures:DSC_1273.jpg\"." number -1728
```

What am I doing wrong?

-J

Comment: While you happen to be trying to automate Photoshop, this is really more of an AppleScript question and is probably better suited for a different StackExchange site such as SuperUser or the Mac site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applescript in Photoshop CS5 is pretty broken according to [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/632681).

Try this:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
    set theImage to "/Users/jedrek/Pictures/temp.jpg"
    with timeout of 5 seconds
        open alias theImage as Camera RAW
    end timeout
end tell
```